# How to store a number from a python 'iter'?

Tags: python, loops, stock

So I need to find the ratio between the prices of two stocks every time those values are queried from the server. However, as a beginner, I cannot seem to find a way to store the price of the two stocks in question so that the ratio between them can be found. Any help?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Query the price once every N seconds.
    for _ in iter(range(N)):
        quotes = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(QUERY.format(random.random())).read())
        i = 0
        """ ----------- Update to get the ratio --------------- """
        for quote in quotes:
            stock, bid_price, ask_price, price = getDataPoint(quote)
            print ("Quoted %s at (bid:%s, ask:%s, price:%s)" % (stock, bid_price, ask_price, price))
            prices[i] = price
            i = i + 1
        print ("Ratio %s" % getRatio(prices[i], prices[i-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the `prices` variable before the loop starts. If you know how many elements there will be you can instantiate like `prices = [0] * n`.

Otherwise you can instantiate as an empty list, `prices = []` and then in your loop add each value to the list like `prices.append(price)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see where prices is defined to be a list
2. You print probably isn't indented correctly - should be inside the loop. Or I am wrong about your code's logic